# Mongo cursor loop slow

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I have the following process for a table that is indexed for rev_timestamp and has about 200 million records. It works extremely fast however during the loop it just pauses for 10-50 seconds every ~10 seconds. Why is that?

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "rev_timestamp")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$lte", 20060201000000)
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$gte", 20060101000000)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
ns = "enwiki.revision"
no <- mongo.count(mongo, ns, query)
cursor <- mongo.find(mongo, ns, query,,list(rev_user=1L,rev_user_text=1L))
# Convert to table
rev_user <- vector("integer", no)
rev_user_text <- vector("character", no)
i <- 1
while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor)) {
  b <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor)
  rev_user[i] <- mongo.bson.value(b, "rev_user")
  rev_user_text[i] <- mongo.bson.value(b, "rev_user_text")
  i <- i + 1
  cat(i,"\n")
}
totalusers <- as.data.frame(list(user=rev_user, user_text=rev_user_text))
```

The logs show that the find completes:

```
Sat Jun  8 23:26:32.471 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37097 #65 (3 connections now open)
Sat Jun  8 23:26:32.821 [conn65] command enwiki.$cmd command: { count: "revision", query: { rev_timestamp: { $lte: 20060201000000.0, $gte: 20060101000000.0 } } } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 6 locks(micros) r:690301 reslen:48 348ms
Sat Jun  8 23:34:59.163 [conn69] getmore enwiki.revision query: { rev_timestamp: { $lte: 20060201000000.0, $gte: 20060101000000.0 } } cursorid:166545066544259763 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 5 locks(micros) r:565614 nreturned:63397 reslen:4194315 325ms
Sat Jun  8 23:35:25.209 [conn65] getmore enwiki.revision query: { rev_timestamp: { $lte: 20060201000000.0, $gte: 20060101000000.0 } } cursorid:164394032580746079 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 17411 locks(micros) r:88392121 nreturned:63496 reslen:4194290 261829ms
Sat Jun  8 23:35:25.209 [conn69] getmore enwiki.revision query: { rev_timestamp: { $lte: 20060201000000.0, $gte: 20060101000000.0 } } cursorid:166545066544259763 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 824 locks(micros) r:23376882 nreturned:63496 reslen:4194290 20979ms
Sat Jun  8 23:35:25.210 [conn65] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [2] server [127.0.0.1:37097] 
Sat Jun  8 23:36:01.980 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39182 #70 (2 connections now open)
Sat Jun  8 23:36:50.724 [conn70] end connection 127.0.0.1:39182 (1 connection now open)
```

However the script gets stuck at item 102 and the progress appears on the server:

```
> db.currentOp()
{
    "inprog" : [
        {
            "opid" : 221329005,
            "active" : true,
            "secs_running" : 156,
            "op" : "getmore",
            "ns" : "enwiki.revision",
            "query" : {
                "rev_timestamp" : {
                    "$lte" : 20060201000000,
                    "$gte" : 20060101000000
                }
            },
            "client" : "127.0.0.1:37097",
            "desc" : "conn65",
            "threadId" : "0x7f63e219d700",
            "connectionId" : 65,
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 7268,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(105797470),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(156781253),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
>
```

Indexes:

```
> db.revision.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "enwiki.revision",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "rev_timestamp" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "enwiki.revision",
        "name" : "rev_timestamp_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "rev_timestamp" : 1,
            "rev_user" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "enwiki.revision",
        "name" : "rev_timestamp_1_rev_user_1"
    }
]
>
```

Is this normal behavior. As far as I know key retrieval should be fast using the cursor. The initial find should take a long time only.

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults     locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     92   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:06 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     58   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:07 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     65   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:08 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     63   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:10 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     84   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:11 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     93   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:12 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     84   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:13 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     64   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:14 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     85   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:15 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0    86g   172g  3.76g     90   enwiki:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0    62b     2k     2   00:20:16
```

Comment: are these large documents being brought over from the server? the way cursors work is the driver fetches documents in batches (default size 100).  So each 100 times through the loop the driver needs to fetch the next batch of documents.  I would suggest looking on the server in the mongod logs - every operation that takes longer than 100ms is logged.  You would be looking for queries that are command "getmore" (that's what says get me the next batch).

Comment: I obtain basically two fields..so really light data. I also update the information.

Comment: it has to read documents from disk so what's happening is a lot of page faulting.  If you look at mongostat while this is running you will see how much total data you have (mmapped) how much is in RAM (res) and how much page faulting is going on (faults) - I'm guessing you will see a lot.

Comment: Yes, you are right..there is lots of page faulting and yielding for the query. Can you see the rest of the stats and tell me if at least memory is allocated properly. I have 8GB

Comment: If you are saying there is 8gb of RAM available then some reconfiguration may be needed - possibly your readahead is set too high since res column is showing only 3.76gb in RAM.

Comment: this looks like a production scenario and some disk issues. Please check your /etc/mongodb.conf. You should have set diaglog=0, profile=0, smallfiles=FALSE